# Full vs Complete Binary Tree Theta Value

Tags: binary-tree, big-o, nodes

Does the total number of nodes in a full binary tree have the same Θ value as the total number of nodes in a complete binary tree with the same height?

Answer (score 0):

Full binary tree of height `h` has a sum of a geometric progression total number of nodes:
`1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^h = 2^(h+1) - 1` thus :

`#Nodes_Full = Θ(2 * 2^h - 1) = Θ(2^h)`

Complete tree of height `h` has **at most** the same number of nodes as a full binary tree. It has **at least** number of nodes when it differs from a full bin-tree by *at most* `2^h - 1` nodes, thus:

`#Nodes_Complete = Θ(2^(h+1) - 1 - (2^h -1)) + Θ(2*2^h - 2^h) = Θ(2^h(2-1)) = Θ(2^h)`

The answer is *yes.*